# Lithium PHP framework - submitted model property disappears before save

Tags: php, frameworks, resources, lithium

I'm working on a project, built with Lithium PHP framework, and have a strange issue:

I have two controllers for users - one for the front-end of the site, and one for admin panel. Both of them have `edit()` method, which calls the `save` method of the `Users` model.

And the problem is this one:

When I attempt to change the password in the admin panel - `$request->data` contains the `confirmPassword` POST field --- BUT --- validation rule for it never triggers.
And when I attempt to register the user on the front-end - the validation for `confirmPassword` triggers.

The methods have one and the same code:

```
public function {add / edit} ($request, $user) {
    if (!$request->data) {
        return array(200, $user);
    }
    $success = $user->save();
    return array($success, $user);
}
```

The validation rule is in the model, & it uses a custom validation, defined in `config/bootstrap/validation.php` with this code:

`Validator::add('matchesPassword', function($value, $format, $options) { ...`

And finally - the website is built with Lithium PHP framework (it's new for me) and uses `li3_resources`, and all the controllers and models extend this `Resource` class.

So ... where could this POST field disappears? ... Any clues? ...

Edit: when I wrote `public function {add / edit} ($request, $user) {` I meant both methods:

```
public function add($request, $user) { ... 
public function edit($request, $user) { ...
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you done a dump of the data (i.e. `$request->data` or `$user->data()`) to see if it is actually there and getting populated? Based on only your description, it seems likely that there is a mismatch between your field name (`confirmPassword`) and the validation rule (`passwordConfirm`). See `models/Users.php`, line 57.

Comment: When I make dump in both `add` and `edit` methods, then `$request->data` contains the `password` and `passwordConfirm` properties with right value, while `$user->data()` does not ... it contains only `password`, and the value there is already encrypted. (In fact - I guess this happens after the actual attempt to save the data.)

Comment: (Btw, it's my mistake for the `confirmPassword`, I don't have anything like this :) ... it's `passwordConfirm` everywhere - in the views, the models, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason for the problem :) ...

On the validation rules, defined in the model by the previous developers, there was this clause:

`'on' => 'create'`

which was causing the validation rule not to trigger when editing.

PS: I tried to dump the rules in the validation itself (in this class - https://github.com/UnionOfRAD/lithium/blob/master/util/Validator.php - in the annonimous function on line 469:

`return static::_filter(__FUNCTION__, $params, function($self, $params) {`

but the dumping never happened ??? ... probably if it worked there - this could save me some time ...